# Problem restoring a .bak file to SQL Server 2018 Express

Tags: sql-server

I try to restore my .back file to SQL Server 2018 Express.

When in SQL Server Management Studio, I right click on the database and click restore database I face this error:

> Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ITaskLauncherService' not found (ObjectExplorer)

What is the problem? please inform me.

Thanks,
Saeed

Comment: Are you sure is it 2018?? I believe SQL express 2018 not yet released

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 in the works - so which one is it?? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your server to find out

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL Server Management Studio as an administrator?

Comment: My SQL management is the final version but I'm not sure about the version of SQL express.